# "No iOS Distribution certificate was found"

Tags: ios, xcode

XCode has started generating this message when I try to refresh the profiles:

"No iOS Distribution Certificate Found. No iOS Distribution certificate was found. However, there is already a certificate request pending. An Agent or Admin must approve this request before you can download your certificate".

However there are no certificates pending approval displayed on the provisioning portal. What's more, I myself am an agent so even if there were a certificate pending approval I would be able to approve it.

What's the best way of getting Xcode / the portal out of this state?

At the moment I can't even compile because of this. Shouldn't I at least be able to develop even if there is no distribution profile?

Comment: I would have to say it's a duplicate, because the usual answer here is to delete everything (certs, profiles, ... etc) and recreate them and import them to Xcode.

Comment: I've done that - deleted all certificates, all profiles, there's nothing left. Xcode still generates that message

Comment: I've also deleted everything from the keychain and started from a totally clean slate. Yet Xcode still generates this error.

Answer (score 2):

Did you happen to recently change your keychain password and maybe blow away the keychain that the CSR was signed with? It will show up as the same keychain name but will be signed differently. I only ask since I accidentally did the same not too long ago.

EDIT:
If you don't see your keychain with a private key associated with it like the bottom two certs below you've got a keychain issue on your development box. The top cert is someone else from my team who I obviously don't have their private key.

[image]

Comment: Hi no I've not touched the keychain for a few months.

Comment: Do your distribution certs have a private key associated with them in Keychain Access still?

Comment: Thanks, things have been working fine for months, this has just recently happened. My keychain looks fine. But I've decided to delete absolutely everything and start from scratch as if I were a new developer, so I've now deleted everything from keychain in addition to everything from the portal and am going to create everything from scratch and hope it works.

Comment: Ooooh.... You don't have any active apps that end users are using, do you??  Revoking your distribution cert will cause any apps signed with it to not load. Behind the scenes Apple does a per-device check for enterprise certs and makes sure they're valid before letting the app run.

Comment: No nothing released yet. However I think you may be mistaken about that? - revoking a certificate is not supposed to have any effect on apps that are currently available in the app store, according to the book "Essential iOS Build and Release".

Comment: Somehow I was under the impression you had an Enterprise account, not an app store account. In your scenario you are obviously 100% correct. Sorry for the confusion.